# How can I fade the screen to black?

Tags: intel-graphics, gpu, openbox

I've got an Ubuntu setup with OpenBox, and I'm just using it to play various media using vlc and feh.

When switching media I have been "fading out" by using `xrandr --brightness` to decrement the screen brightness, then swap out the media, then fade back in.

This approach is a bit tedious, and on my new Intel Ivy Bridge GPU, it looks terrible and lags horribly.

**Is there another way to simply fade out / back in, perhaps with a screensaver or other X command?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying to solve this problem by using `wmctrl` the window management controller.

I can switch to a blank screen, swap out the media, then switch back to the original screen.

All I need to do now is get a transition happening when switching screens, but it appears openbox does not support transitions..
I suppose that deserves [it's own question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243686/how-can-i-transition-between-virtual-desktops-on-openbox).